# When every minimal subgroup is contained in the center

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups, proof-explanation

> Let $G$ be a finite group and $(*)$ be the property:
>
> $(*)$: Every minimal normal subgroup is contained in the center.
>
> $(a)$ Let $N$ and $M$ be normal subgroups of $G$, both of which satisfy $(*)$. Then prove:
>   $NM$ satisfies $(*)$.
>
> $(b)$ If $G$ satisfies $(*)$, then prove: every normal subgroup of $G$ satisfies $(*)$.

I would also agree that it may be a possible duplicate of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1401442/every-minimal-normal-subgroup-is-contained-in-the-center). However, unfortunately, I could find that post a little complicated to understand and not well developed, of which the ***logic, notation, and language*** might ***not have been so polished***.

It would be greatly appreciated, if you could throw light on this question and be kind enough to ***give an  elegant proof***. Thanks a lot! $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure that I can achieve elegance.

Let's deal with (b); then (a) is a corollary. So we have a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$.

Step 1: Let $K$ be a minimal normal subgroup of $N$ with $K\not\leqslant Z(N)$. Then $K\cap Z(N)=1$ or we are done.

Step 2: Consider $K^G$. It is not hard to prove that this is a normal subgroup of $G$, and indeed that $K^G=K_1\times K_2\times\dots\times K_s$, where $K_1=K$ and each $K_i$ is a $G$-conjugate of $K$, and each is normal in $N$.

Step 3: Let $L$ be a minimal normal subgroup of $G$ lying in $K^G$. Then by hypothesis $L\leqslant Z(G)$, and so $L\leqslant Z(N)$.

Step 4: Let $1\not=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_s)\in L\cap Z(N)$, where $x_i\in K_i$. Now $N$ fixes each $K_i$, so we have that $N$ centralises each $x_i$.

Step 5: Some $x_i\not=1$, so we get $K_i\cap Z(N)\not=1$. Conjugating by an appropriate element of $G$ we get that $K_1\cap Z(N)\not=1$; this is a contradiction, so $K\leqslant Z(N)$.

[I think Step 2 is standard stuff.]

Comment: Why could we claim $L$ to be in $K^G$?

Comment: $K^G$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ so we can choose a minimal normal subgroup inside it.

Comment: Step 3: Don’t we generally have $K^G=N$? (since $K^G\trianglelefteq G, K^G\subseteq N$ and $N$ being minimal normal in $G$)

Comment: @Benny: $N$ is any old normal subgroup.

Comment: @ancientmathematician $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @ancientmathematician Hello, would you be so kind as to tell me how to apply $(b)$ to $(a)$, as you said $(a)$ then is a collary?

Comment: @Math. Apologies, I thought it was but cannot recall why. If I can't I'll delete that bit.

Answer (score 0):

I have an argument for (a) in the case  $N \cap M = 1$, which implies $NM = N \times M$. Let $K$ be some minimal normal subgroup of $NM$. Then by considering the quotient $KN / N \unlhd NM / N \cong M$ either $KN \le N$ or $KN / N$ is minimal normal in $MN / N$, in the last case $[x,y] \in N$ for each $x \in K, y \in NM$ by assumption. Similar by looking at $NM / M$ we find $K \le M$ or $[x,y] \in M$ for each $x \in K, y \in NM$. As $[N, G] \le N$ and $[M, G] \le M$ by normality, in all cases we have $[x,y] \le M \cap N = 1$ for $x \in K, y \in NM$, which gives the claim.

If $N \cap M \ne 1$ maybe (b) can help in the sense that we can deduce that property $(*)$ then holds for $M \cap N$.

**EDIT** (5/11/19): I found a proof for the general case which works quite different. Let $K$ be some minimal normal subgroup in $NM$. Then as $N$ is normal we have that $[K, N] \le N \cap K$ is normal in $NM$, which implies $[K,N] = 1$ or $[K,N] = K$. Assume $[K,N] = K$. Let $L \le K$ be some minimal normal subgroup of $N$ in $[K,N]$ and consider $H = \langle L^g \mid g \in NM \rangle$, which is normal in $NM$. Hence $H = [K,N] = K$.
The groups $L^g$ are also minimal normal in $N$ by normality of $N$ and the fact that non-trivial homomorphic images are minimal normal in its image, hence $H$ is a direct product of some subset of these conjugages. By assumption the factors are all in the center of $N$, hence $K$ is in the center of $N$, i.e. $[K,N] = 1$ contradicting the assumption. Simlar we find $[K,M] = 1$. So $[K,MN] = [K,M][K,N] = 1$, i.e. $K$ is in the center of $NM$. $\square$

Answer (score 0):

**Another proof for part (a)**

Fix any $H\triangleleft_mNM$.

**Claim 1:** $H\subseteq N\implies H\subseteq Z(N)$

Assume that $H\subseteq N$ and pick $A\triangleleft_mN$, $A\subseteq H$. By hypothesis $A\subseteq Z(N)$. Moreover, given $y\in M$, we have $A^y\triangleleft N^y=N$. It follows that $A^M\triangleleft N$. But $M$ normalizes $A^M$ and so $A^M\triangleleft NM$. Since $A^M\subseteq H^M=H\triangleleft_m NM$, we get $A^M=H$. Hence, to show that $H\subseteq Z(N)$ it is enough to verify that $A^y\subseteq Z(N)$. But this is clear because $Z(N)\triangleleft G$.

**Claim 2:** $H\subseteq N\implies H\subseteq Z(NM)$

Assume that $H\subseteq N$. By Claim 1 $H\subseteq Z(N)$. If —in addition— $H\subseteq M$, Claim 1 applied to $M$ implies that $H\subseteq Z(M)$. It follows that $H\subseteq Z(NM)$. Otherwise, if $H\not\subseteq M$, given that both $H$ and $M$ are normal in $NM$, we deduce that $H\cap M=\langle1\rangle$ and so $H\leftrightarrow M$ (*commutes with*). Therefore, in this case we also have $H\subseteq Z(NM)$.

**Conclusion:**
Claims 1 and 2 reduce the question to the case $H\cap N=\langle1\rangle$. By the symmetry between $N$ and $M$ we may also assume that $H\cap M=\langle1\rangle$. But then $H\leftrightarrow N$ and $H\leftrightarrow M$, which implies $H\subseteq Z(NM)$.